# How to show this set $\mathfrak{B}=\left \{ A \in \mathfrak{A}: \int f \mathbb{1}_Ad\mu=\int g \mathbb{1}_Ad\mu \right \}$ is Dynkin-System?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a set, $\mathfrak{A}$ a $\sigma$-Algebra and $\mu$ a measure of ($\Omega$,$\mathfrak{A}$). Then $f,g : \Omega \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\int f d\mu=\int g d\mu$.

$$\mathfrak{B}=\left \{ A \in \mathfrak{A}: \int f \mathbb{1}_Ad\mu=\int g \mathbb{1}_Ad\mu \right \} $$

I have to show that $ \mathfrak{B}$ is a Dynkin-System.

By Definition a Dynkin-System is:

- **(D1)** $\Omega \in \mathfrak{D}$
- **(D2)** $A,B \in \mathfrak{D}, A \subseteq B \Rightarrow  B\setminus A \in \mathfrak {D} $
- **(D3)** $A_n \in \mathfrak{D}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $A_n \cap A_m=\emptyset$, $m\neq n \Rightarrow \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \in \mathfrak{D}$

For **(D1)** it is almost given by assumption that $\int f d\mu=\int g d\mu$ and it is satisfied.

For **(D2)**, I choose $A,B \in \mathfrak{A} $ such that $B \setminus A$ is still in $\mathfrak{A}$ and when I take this in Indicator function $\mathbb{1}_{B\setminus A}$ it holds $\int f \mathbb{1}_{B\setminus A}d\mu=\int g \mathbb{1}_{B \setminus A}d\mu$

And I don't know how to show for the **(D3)**!!

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by the formulation of your question. Do you **assume** that the integral $\int f \, d\mu$ exists (in the sense that $\int |f| \, d\mu < \infty$)?

Comment: @saz yes, this from assumption!

Comment: I see. Then note that $$\int \left( \sum_{n \geq 1} 1_{A_n} \right) |f| \, d\mu \leq \int |f| \, d\mu$$ (because the sets are disjoint) and use the dominated convergence theorem.